# Heroku Python Flask serves index.html page

Tags: python, heroku, flask

Flask can't serve an index.html page... it seems that it doesn't recognize the static folder

[image]

It serves the index.html in this way

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, url_for, redirect


# set the project root directory as the static folder, you can set others.
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def root():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return redirect(url_for('static', filename='index.html'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
```

But I receive an Internal Server Error

Comment: Run `heroku logs` and add the error's traceback here in a code block. That will help.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a stupid suggestion but maybe try renaming the directory to 'templates' and use the render_template function. From my experience I've only ever used redirect(url_for()) to point to a different function in Python i.e.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def root():
    if request.method == 'GET':

        return render_template('index.html')


    if request.method == 'POST':

        return redirect(url_for('another_function'))

@app.route('/another_route', methods=['GET'])
def another_function():
       if request.method == 'GET':
         ....
```